# QTouchEvent strange behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

What happends with that code is that when i want to use QGraphicsView::event() then GameView::event() doesn't catch QTouchEvent,but when i don't don't use QGraphicsView::event() everything works fine. I would like to use this parent
method, becouse i need to handle default events.

---

```
#include "gameview.h"
#include "QDebug"
#include <QGesture>
#include <QGestureEvent>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QTapGesture>
GameView::GameView(QWidget *parent):QGraphicsView (parent)
{
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_StaticContents);
    qDebug()<<"I am in GameView  constructor\n";
}

GameView::~GameView()
{
    qDebug()<<"I am in GameView deconstructor\n";
}

bool GameView::event(QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
    {
        QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> touchPoints = static_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event)->touchPoints();
        foreach (const QTouchEvent::TouchPoint &touchPoint, touchPoints)
        {
            switch (touchPoint.state())
            {
            case Qt::TouchPointStationary:
                // don't do anything if this touch point hasn't moved
                continue;
            case Qt::TouchPointPressed:
            {
                qDebug()<<"Touch Pressed";
                break;
            }
            case Qt::TouchPointReleased:
            {
                qDebug()<<"Touch Release";
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                // qDebug()<<"Default";
                 break;
            }
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        return QGraphicsView::event(event);//if i comment that line then 
 //its works 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wild guess: QGraphicsView is a QAbstractScrollArea subclass. As such, you're supposed to set `Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents` on the `viewport()`, not onto itself, and probably use `viewportEvent` to get events directed to the viewport. See also https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#enabling-touch-events and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewportEvent

Comment: I have tried to override viewportEvent , but android compiler says that viewportEvent is not a member of QGraphicsView.
On desktop i dont have such error.